# Максимально разумный размер файла xml для хранения данных

Tags: c#, xml, хранение-данных

В программе использую Datatable. При запуске считываю в таблицу данные из xml файла. В ходе работы программы изменяемые данные снова пишу в xml файл. При этом данные - аккумулируются, соответственно файл растёт. Также данные датируются и устаревают со временем. Возникла мысль, проверять размер файла xml и в случае превышения некоего объёма - старые данные из него вычищать. Просьба посоветовать, до какого предела можно позволять разрастаться xml файлу для шустрой работы с ним. Понимаю, что не обязательно привязываться к размеру файла и данные можно чистить просто по датам, но хочу всё же отталкиваться именно от размера файла

Comment: Чем меньше файл, тем быстрее работает. Ответ очевиден. Все зависит от Вашей конкретной задачи, железа и.т.д.

Comment: На мой взгляд XML нужен для обмена данными. Для хранения стоит использовать СУБД или просто реляционную БД, в зависимости от задачи. XML в качестве хранения данных - медленный формат. Если большое количество документов, то тем более. Как я понял, документ у вас один. От железа будет зависеть многое. Какое понятие вы вкладываете в "шустрое" - не понятно. Совет простой: тестируйте. Программно увеличьте количество узлов и пробуйте.

Comment: А в чем смысл хранить в нем старые данные, если файл целиком каждый раз перезаписывается? Просто не пишите в файл ненужную инфу и вычищать её не придется.

Comment: Проще замерять время при считывании (или записи). Если >N% от нормы, то ...

Comment: Доберусь до дома (и если будет время и желание), напишу длиииииный ответ на тему размера файла xml. Только не закрывайте вопрос, ироды.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не утруждайте себя

Answer (score 4):

XML - громоздкий формат, что ведёт к большому размеру файлов и большому потреблению места на носителях. Давайте рассмотрим способы уменьшения потребления ресурсов.

1. Радикальный способ: рассмотрите возможность отказа от XML и перехода к другому формату файлов: это могут быть json, yaml, бинарные форматы, наподобие protobuf, и прочие. Кроме уменьшения размеров это может привести и к большей скорости обработки файлов (запись-чтение-парсинг), и к более быстрой передаче по сети. К тому же многие из них тоже являются общепринятыми стандартами, наряду с XML.
2. Сжатие. Текстовые форматы почти всегда хорошо сжимаются архиваторами. XML не является исключением. Повторяющиеся теги, само собой, будут сжаты архиватором в один экземпляр. В дотнете легко и просто можно использовать `GZipStream`, `DeflateStream`. Конечно, можно применять и сжатие в форматы 7Z, Zip, RAR и т. п.

   - Можно включить сжатие диска на уровне операционной системы (приложение даже не будет знать об этом). Естественно, сжатие применимо для любых форматов.
     P.S. Файлы офисного пакета: xlsx, docx - это зазипованный xml.
3. Кодировка файлов. Для текстовых форматов выбор правильной кодировки является очень важным делом. Если взять однобайтовую ANSI - то размер файлов будет минимальный, но мы будем ограничены в количестве возможных символов. Соответственно, если нам нужны символы из разных алфавитов и другие символы за пределами восьми бит, придётся взять многобайтовую кодировку. Какую? Например, UTF-32: весь диапазон Юникода в нашем распоряжении! Однако, четыре байта на символ - не слишком ли расточительно?
   Стандартный и самый распространённый вариант - UTF-8. Пожалуй, эта кодировка оптиимальна для XML: часто повторяющиеся в нём символы: `<`, `>`, `"`, `'`, `=`, `?` - будут кодироваться одним байтом. А если ещё и названия тегам и атрибутам давать английские, то они тоже будут кодироваться компактно.
   Однако, в некоторых случаях UTF-16 может оказаться выгодней: там где в UTF-8 на один символ может понадобиться три и более байтов, в UTF-16 будет достаточно двух. Но это нужно уточнять на деле, в зависимости от предполагаемых для хранения данных.

   - А если ещё и вместо идиотского представления конца строки двумя символами `LR`/`LF` (`\r\n`), как зачем-то сделано в Windows, использовать один символ, как сделано в Unix/Linux/MacOS, то можно выиграть ещё несколько процентов. Тут вопрос в том, способны ли на это используемые сериализаторы/парсеры.
   - Не указывать BOM. А что - экономим ещё пару байтов в каждом файле...
4. Размер кластера файловой системы. Как известно, размер кластера может варьироваться в разных системах. Например, от 512 байт до 32 или даже 64 кб. Стандартный размер по умолчанию обычно 4 кб. Таким образом, если большинство файлов у нас имеют небольшой размер, не более нескольких сотен байтов (а самих файлов очень много), то на каждый из них будет выделено всё равно по одному кластеру: лишний расход места на харде очевиден. В данной ситуации может оказаться очень выгодно переформатировать диск под маленький размер кластера.
   И наоборот, если файлы у нас большие, минимум сотни килобайт, то для них будет выгоднее форматирование файловой системы под большие кластеры: чем меньше количество кластеров, тем меньше места отводится под файловую таблицу. К тому же, на больших кластерах происходит быстрее чтение-запись больших файлов.
   Нельзя не отметить, что архивирование довольно эффективно решает эту проблему: файлы в архиве хранятся последовательно как единое целое, поэтому маленькие файлы не будут занимать по целому кластеру. Причём можно применять даже архивирование без сжатия.

Это всё были административные меры, применимые к любому формату и непосредственно не связанные с XML. Теперь переходим к нему самому.

5. Следует отказаться от форматирования с индентацией. Такой формат удобнее для чтения человеком, но любой специализированный xml-редактор может на лету выполнять форматирование. Без отступов будет значительная экономия на пробельных символах.

   ```
   <person>
       <name>Bob</name>
       <age>42</age>
   </person>

   <person><name>Bob</name><age>42</age></person>
   ```

   В крайнем случае, использовать один `TAB` вместо нескольких пробелов.
6. Вместо узлов-тегов можно использовать атрибуты: название будет представлено всего в одном экземпляре, вместо двух.

   ```
   <person><name>Bob</name><age>42</age></person>

   <person name="Bob" age="42"/>
   ```

   Ещё раз упомяну о желательности имён на английском языке: это может положительно сказаться на кодировании букв всего одним байтом в случае UTF-8.
7. Хранение XML-схем. Иногда применяется помещение XmlSchema в файл XML с данными. Это зачастую довольно удобно, но при наличии большого количества однотипных файлов, валидируемых этой схемой, приводит к бездумному повторению одной и той же схемы во всех файлах. Следует хранить xsd в одном экземпляре, отдельно от xml-файлов с данными.
8. Значения по умолчанию. Несложно догадаться, что если данные известны заранее, то их можно не сохранять в каждом файле. Кроме ручной реализации этого способа, при самостоятельной записи и чтении, есть и автоматические.

   - Пример сериализации со значением по умолчанию. На помощь нам приходит `XmlSerializer`, с его способностью не записывать свойства, помеченные атрибутом `DefaultValue` (для десериализации дефолтные значения необходимо задавать в конструкторе):

     ```
     public class Person
     {
         public Person()
         {
             Gender = "female";
         }
         public string Name { get; set; }
         [DefaultValue("female")]
         public string Gender { get; set; }
     }

     var list = new List<Person> {
         new Person { Name = "Bob", Gender = "male" },
         new Person { Name = "Alice", Gender = "female" }
     };
     xs.Serialize(Console.Out, list);
     ```
   - Вариент с использованием XmlSchema, в которой можно указывать дефолтные значения (что является очень мощным способом, хоть и часто критикуемым).

     ```
     <person pet="cat">
         <name>Bob</name>
         <age>42</age>
     </person>
     <person>
         <name>Alice</name>
         <age>21</age>
     </person>
     ```

     Видите суслика? А он есть!

     ```
     <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="person">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
           <xs:element name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
         </xs:sequence>
         <xs:attribute name="pet" type="xs:string" default="gopher" />
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
     ```

     В xsd задано значение по умолчанию `gopher` для атрибута `pet`.
9. Использовать короткие префиксы пространств имён. Наиболее частый неймспейс сделать namespace by default (префикса вообще не будет).

   ```
   <longprefix:person xmlns:longprefix="example.com">
       <longprefix:name>Bob</longprefix:name>
       <longprefix:age>42</longprefix:age>
   </longprefix:person>

   <p:person xmlns:p="example.com">
       <p:name>Bob</p:name>
       <p:age>42</p:age>
   </p:person>
   ```
10. Выкинуть все комментарии (по возможности).

    ```
    <person>
        <!-- Имя человека -->
        <name>Alice</name>
        <!-- Возраст человека -->
        <age>21</age>
    </person>
    ```

    Для однотипных данных не нужны комментарии в каждом файле. Достаточно одного экземпляра описания в документации (схеме).

    ```
    <xs:element name="person">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <!-- Имя человека -->
          <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
          <!-- Возраст человека -->
          <xs:element name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    ```

Далее я мог бы рассказать о совсем уж специфичных способах работы с xml, приводящим к нехватке памяти при использовании потоковых (sic!) `XmlReader`/`XmlWriter`. Однако, сообщение уже превысило разумные пределы.

11. Скажу лишь, что нужно заранее тщательно проектировать структуру xml, чтобы впоследствии можно было извлечь желаемые данные за один проход.
    Например, часто встречается нечто подобное:

    ```
    <root>
      <foo>
        <data id="1">something</data>
      </foo>

      <bar>
        <id>1</id>
      </bar>
    </root>
    ```

    Данные нужно извлечь по индексу, который расположен в другой части файла. Вот и приходится либо в два прохода это делать, либо использовать словарь/хэшсет для аккумуляции информации.
12. Не удержался. Ещё экзотический пример. Часто люди задаются вопросом: как дописывать информацию в файл xml? Вариант для извращенцев:

    ```
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = true };

    // Создаём файл xml.
    using (var fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create))
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, settings))
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("root");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            writer.WriteElementString("foo", i.ToString());
    }

    // Дописываем информацию в конец файла. Без его перезаписи!
    using (var fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Append))
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, settings))
    {
        writer.WriteComment("bar");
        writer.WriteComment("baz");
    }

    // Читаем из конца.
    var xml = XDocument.Load("test.txt");
    var last = xml.LastNode;

    // Или так.
    var comments = xml.DescendantNodes().OfType<XComment>();
    foreach (var c in comments)
        Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
    ```
13. Дописать информацию в начало xml-файла без его перезаписи? Да не вопрос! Опять на помощь приходит XmlSchema и значения по умолчанию. Предлагаю додуматься самостоятельно, как это сделать. А мне пора спать.

Резюмируя: при должной сноровке можно комфортно (ну-у...) работать с файлами любого размера.